# javascript regex syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have made my self a custom javascript syntax highlighter

```
<p id="data">// return
function getdata() {
    // return hi
     return "Hi";
}</p>
data = $('p#data').html();
data = data.replace(/\/\/.*$/gm, "<font color=#878A85>$&</font>");
data = data.replace(new RegExp(getRegx('return'), 'gmi'), "<font color=#C97F00>$&</font>");
$('p#data').html(data);
```

Now, what my problem is that it will replace the return keyword in the comments also is there a way to avoid this and how do i number each line i don't want to use any pre built script because i am only going to use php script i don't want more stuff.

Comment: FYI: font-tags are deprecated since html 4. I suggest using a span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use negative lookahead `/return(?!.*<\/font>)$/`

```
<p id="data">
    // return
    function getdata() {
       // return hi
       return "Hi";
    }
</p>
data = $('p#data').html();
data = data.replace(/\/\/.*$/gm, "<font color=#878A85>$&</font>");
data = data.replace(new RegExp(getRegx('return(?!.*<\/font>$)'), 'gmi'), "<font color=#C97F00>$&</font>");
$('p#data').html(data);
```